# KeyError: “None of [] are in the columns” when using the Python Pandas set_index function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, methods

I have created the original dataframe from a CSV file

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Sam\cars.csv')
```

Which produces a df with the following columns

```
Index(['mpg', 'cylinders', 'displacement', 'horsepower', 'weight',
   'acceleration', 'model_year', 'origin', 'name'],
  dtype='object')
```

I can set one of these columns as an index

```
df.set_index('cylinders')
```

I then successfully created a copy of this original df and inserted a combined name year column

```
df_name = df.copy()

df_name ['name_year'] = df.name + ' - 19' + df.model_year.astype(str)
```

However, whenever trying to assign a column as an index, be it the new name_year column or otherwise, I am met with the same keyError message

```
df_car_index = df_name.copy() 

df_car_index = df_car_index.set_index('horsepower', inplace=True)
df_car_index

KeyError: "None of ['horsepower'] are in the columns"
```

Comment: Unrelated, but assigning back the `set_index` call  when using `inplace=True` will invalidate `df_car_index` (it will be `None`) and the reference to the dataframe will be lost

Comment: Anyway, try to `print(df_car_index.columns)` and see if it has a column `horsepower` (according to the error message, it does not).

Comment: Thank you for your reply

It does appear to have horsepower as a column 

df_car_index = df_name.copy()
print(df_car_index.columns)


Index (['mpg', 'cylinders', 'displacement', 'weight', 'acceleration',
       'model_year', 'origin', 'name', 'name_year'],
      dtype = 'object')

Comment: I'm confused. You wrote that it does appear to have `horsepower` columns, but it is not there in the output you provided (please also add it to the question). That is exactly the problem.

Comment: I have no idea what we did but it appears to be working now, I can return any column as index, including name year

Answer (score 5):

When you set the column as an index, it is moved to index and removed from columns. Thus `set_index()` only needs to be run once when you pass `inplace=True`, making it a permanent change.

If you want to revert the index change, you can do, `df.reset_index(inplace=True)`. The column that was moved to index will be re-added to the columns. Like `set_index()`, this code needs to be run only once, re-running it will cause errors.

You can find a demonstration of how to set a custom index and revert it back [on this tutorial by Data School](https://youtu.be/OYZNk7Z9s6I?t=433).

Another important point is: If you try to add another index over the custom index that was set from one of the columns, it overwrites the custom index column, and effectively deletes it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to programming and Data Science, and ran into this issue with Kaggle, similar to Jupyter and solved this issue by restaring/clearing the outputs and running all of the code over again. Instead of deleting cells I no longer needed, I was cutting the cells so code that I thought were gone still remained in the memory, messing with my updated code.

Comment: I suppose another fix is to close out of everything and reopening it, which may be what you did to solve your issue.

Answer (score -1):

You need to run that part of the code just once. When that column is set as an index and you run the code again, you will get the error.

Comment: Consider adding some code to your answer to explain what "that" code is.